# Codename one-Converting to new gui builder error

Tags: java, codenameone

I have tried to use "convert to new Gui builder", from a project created in the old Gui builder. Conversion works successfully, but after I run it, it displays an error.

I want to convert Old to New gui builder. How do i solve it?

```
    ant -f C:\\Users\\user1\\Desktop\\appversions\\renew2\\29-6-Convertnew -Dnb.internal.action.name=run run
Akmi_Career.java unmodified, skipping
Processing GUI builder file: C:\Users\user1\Desktop\appversions\renew2\29-6-Convertnew\src\com\codename1\akmiapp\gui\AnakoinoseisTab.java
Processing GUI builder file: C:\Users\user1\Desktop\appversions\renew2\29-6-Convertnew\src\com\codename1\akmiapp\gui\Bonus_Card.java
ContactWeb.java unmodified, skipping
Processing GUI builder file: C:\Users\user1\Desktop\appversions\renew2\29-6-Convertnew\src\com\codename1\akmiapp\gui\Egramateia.java
C:\Users\ksak\Desktop\appversions\renew2\29-6-Convertnew\build.xml:470: 
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.codename1.build.client.GenerateGuiSources.appendCommandIcon(GenerateGuiSources.java:863)
    at com.codename1.build.client.GenerateGuiSources.updateProperties(GenerateGuiSources.java:660)
    at com.codename1.build.client.GenerateGuiSources.constructComponentsHierarchy(GenerateGuiSources.java:311)
    at com.codename1.build.client.GenerateGuiSources.generateGuiSource(GenerateGuiSources.java:299)
    at com.codename1.build.client.GenerateGuiSources.generateGuiSource(GenerateGuiSources.java:231)
    at com.codename1.build.client.GenerateGuiSources.execute(GenerateGuiSources.java:202)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.UnknownElement.execute(UnknownElement.java:293)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor79.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.dispatch.DispatchUtils.execute(DispatchUtils.java:106)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Task.perform(Task.java:348)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Target.execute(Target.java:435)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Target.performTasks(Target.java:456)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeSortedTargets(Project.java:1405)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeTarget(Project.java:1376)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.helper.DefaultExecutor.executeTargets(DefaultExecutor.java:41)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeTargets(Project.java:1260)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.module.bridge.impl.BridgeImpl.run(BridgeImpl.java:286)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.module.run.TargetExecutor.run(TargetExecutor.java:555)
    at org.netbeans.core.execution.RunClassThread.run(RunClassThread.java:153)
BUILD FAILED (total time: 0 seconds)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems to be a bug with processing commands in a menu. We have a fix for it. This fix should be out next week. We hope to make a major release next week for some new features and it should include this fix.

Comment: Thank you. Looking forward to it. Should i download a new version, or just check for updates in neatbeans?

Comment: This should arrive on its own, you won't need a plugin update it will update via Codename One Settings. We'll probably push this out on Sunday or Saturday because we have a huge/disruptive change coming out https://www.codenameone.com/blog/new-build-cloud.html

Comment: I am still unable to convert to new gui builder. I assume the new version is not out yet?

Comment: It's been out for a few days. If you launch the update from Codename One Settings what's printed out? What's the content of the file in your home directory under `.codenameone/UpdateStatus.properties`